# Twilio messages API does not allow variables or concatenated strings in its message body

Tags: node.js, sms, twilio

I'm trying to send an SMS which contains a generated token to my phone. If I pass a normal hard-coded string to the message body, I get the text but if I pass in a variable or concatenated string, I get an error showing up on my Twilio dashboard: `30003 - Unreachable destination handset`. However, I get a success response from Twilio even though it failed to send.

```js
// twilio.js

const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

exports.sendSMS = async ({ phone, message }) => {
  await client.messages.create({
    to: phone,
    from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
    body: message // this doesn't work
    // body: 'Hello' works
  });
};

// somewhere in other-file.js

const token = generateToken() // abc123
const message = `Your token is ${token}.`;

await twilio.sendSMS({
  phone: user.phone,
  message
});
```

Is there a workaround to this? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have tried your code. Don't see anything wrong with this. have yu tried console.log value of message when you use it via variable?

Comment: There are a few [reasons you may receive a 30003 error](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30003) and they should have nothing to do with the way you format the string for your message body. Note also that since 30003 is an error regarding delivery of the message it can take time for that error to be received which is why you don't see it in the initial API response. Can you read the [error docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30003) and see if those reasons may be the case your message is failing.